# Problem with active-record and sql

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a little problem: I can't compose sql-query inside AR.

So, I have `Project` and `Task` models, `Project has_many Tasks`. `Task` has aasm-field (i.e. "status"; but it doesn't matter, i can be simple int or string field).

So, I want on my projects index page list all (last) projects and for every project I want count it's active, pending and resolved (for example) tasks.

Like this, just look:

- First project (1 active, 2 pending,
  10 resolved)
- Second projects (4
  active, 2 pending, 2 resolved)

So, sure I can do it with `@projects = Project.all` and then in view:

```
- @projects.each do |project| 
  = project.title
  = project.tasks(:conditions => {:status => "active"}).count #sure it should be in model, just for example
  = project.tasks(:conditions => {:status => "pending"}).count
  # ...
- end
```

This is good, but makes 1+N*3 (for 3 task statuses) queries, i want 1. The question is simple: `how?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the right answer is:

```
Projects.all(:joins  => :tasks, 
             :select => 'projects.*, 
                         sum(tasks.status="pending") as pending_count, 
                         sum(tasks.status = "accepted") as accepted_count, 
                         sum(tasks.status = "rejected") as rejected_count', 
             :group  => 'projects.id')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a counter cache in your project model to prevent needing to recount all tasks on each display of the index page - have an active_count, pending_count and resolved_count, and update them whenever the task changes state.

If you just want to modify your existing code, try:

```
project.tasks.count(:conditions => "status = 'active'")
```

You could also add a scope to your task model that would enable you to do something like:

```
project.tasks.active.count
```

*EDIT*

Ok so I'm half asleep - got the wrong impression from your question :/

Yep, you can do it in one query - use find_by_sql to get your projects along with the grouped counts for the tasks. You'll be able to access the group counts in the resulting array of projects.

Comment: Have you any idea except counter_cache? I don't want to use them, so I'll use them in the last case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do a find with grouping and counting. Something like:

```
status_counts = project.tasks.find(:all, 
                                   :group => 'status', 
                                   :select => 'status, count(*) as how_many')
```

This will return you a list of `Task`-like objects with `status` and `how_many` attributes which you can then use to give your summary. E.g.

```
<%= status_counts.map { |sc| "#{sc.how_many} #{sc.status} }.to_sentence %>
```

Comment: I need something like exactly this, but I want to do something like @projects = >> current_user.projects.find(:all, :joins => :tasks, :select => "projects.*, count(tasks.id) as active", :group => "status")

Comment: but i really cannot divide active/inactive/etc.

Comment: I want to get something like "projects.id, projects.title, active_count, inactive_count, pending_count".

Comment: I'm not entirely confident you can just do one massive query to get you all the projects with all the task counts. If that is what you want then the counter_cache approach suggested by Mr. Matt is definitely the best.

Comment: If I would select only recent tasks, counter_cache will now work (or I should reload counters every day by cron). And yes, I really need exactly what you described. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could, in your Project controller:

1. Fetch all your projects: `Project.all`
2. Fetch all your tasks: `Task.all`

Then, create a hash with something like

```
@statuses = Hash.new
@tasks.each do |t|
  @statuses[:t.project_id][:t.status] += 1
end
```

And then use it in your view:

```
First project (<%= @statuses[:@project.object_id][:active] %> active)
```

This is not the prefect solution, but it is easy to implement and only use two (big) queries. Of course, this would re-create a hash every time, so you might want to look into database indexes or cache systems.

Also, [named scopes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html#method-i-named_scope) would be interesting, like `Task.active`.

Comment: There can be A LOT OF tasks, so I don't want to fetch all records, only COUNT() of them.